# Subscripts with tables

Tags: tables

I have a magic square with cards as entries, and I am trying to consider all magic squares of order 3 (there are 8). My goal is to denote each square with a subscript M_1, ... , M_8. Right now I have some code that produces the desired look, but I am pretty sure it is a very ineffective way of going about what I am trying to achieve (the placement of the subscript M_i):

```
\begin{center}
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\fourh & \nineh & \twoh\\
\hline
\treh & \fiveh & \sevh\\
\hline
\eigh & \Ah & \sixh\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\kern-1em\,
\begin{tabular}{c}
{}\\
{}\\
{}\\
$M_1$\\
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\end{center}
```

When compiled, this yields the following image:

[image]

That's great, but as my code above reveals, that's probably not the best way of getting the subscripted M where I want it to be. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How about [an alternative display](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XeReq.png)?

Answer (score 4):

You can add a fourth column

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,graphicx}
\newcommand{\mypicture}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|l}
\cline{1-3}
\mypicture & \mypicture & \mypicture \\
\cline{1-3}
\mypicture & \mypicture & \mypicture \\
\cline{1-3}
\mypicture & \mypicture & \mypicture &\multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\smash{\raisebox{-2ex}{$M_1$}}}\\
\cline{1-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now time for over kill solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\mypicture}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\node[inner sep=0pt] (a) {\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\mypicture & \mypicture & \mypicture \\
\hline
\mypicture & \mypicture & \mypicture \\
\hline
\mypicture & \mypicture & \mypicture \\
\cline{1-3}
\end{tabular}
};
\node[anchor=west,inner xsep=1pt] at (a.south east) {$M_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand{\mypicture}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,nodes={anchor=center}](m)
    {
     \mypicture & \mypicture & \mypicture \\
     \mypicture & \mypicture & \mypicture \\
     \mypicture & \mypicture & \mypicture \\
      };
\node[anchor=west,inner sep=0pt] at (m-3-3.south east) {$M_1$};
\foreach \x[count=\y] in {1,2,3}{
\draw (m-3-1.south west) |- (m-1-3.north east);
\draw (m-\x-1.south west) -- (m-\x-3.south east);
\draw (m-1-\y.north east) -- (m-3-\y.south east);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make the M_1 appear more like as I have it in my sample image? That is, have it appearing more like a subscript than just on the right?

Comment: @induktio You want to lower `$M_1$`?. I am on my way to post 2 tikz answers, one using `node` and other using `matrix`.

Answer (score 1):

I have not your definitions of cards, hence my definitions of them are to be removed, of course. Probably the `[b]` option is everything needed in this case. (And additional vertical move of $M_1$ may be easily obtained by `\raisebox{dist}{text}`).

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\def\fourh{fourh}
\def\nineh{nineh}
\def\twoh{twoh}
\def\treh{treh}
\def\fiveh{fiveh}
\def\sevh{sevh}
\def\eigh{eigh}
\def\Ah{Ah}
\def\sixh{sixh}

\begin{center}
%\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\fourh & \nineh & \twoh\\
\hline
\treh & \fiveh & \sevh\\
\hline
\eigh & \Ah & \sixh\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
$\mkern4mu M_1$
%\kern-1em\,
%\begin{tabular}{c}
%{}\\
%{}\\
%{}\\
%$M_1$\\
%\end{tabular}
%\egroup
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just for others who may be interesting: the cards I am using are defined according to the "poker" package.

Comment: @induktio The MWE **with** this information could save some unneeded work.