# Drawing a square with certain labeling

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using the symmetries of the square to make a neat application to magic squares, but I am unsure about how to represent the symmetries of the square effectively. I would like to be able to typeset the following square as found in my abstract algebra book:

[image]

Unfortunately, I am not all that familiar with `tikz`, and I am pretty sure that is what is needed here. Does anyone know how to make the square above using a `tikzpicture` environment? Another goal is to be able to produce a figure as follows: 
[image]

I am completely unaware as to how to produce the image above that displays the transformations, but the first image that indicates the symmetries of the square--I found the following code in the `tikz` manual:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \name/\angle in {a/0,b/90,c/180,d/270}
\node (\name) at (\angle:1) {$\name$};
\path[->] (b) edge (a)
edge (c)
edge [-,dotted] (d)
(c) edge (a)
edge (d)
(d) edge (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This, however, does not really give me what I want at all. Does anyone know how to produce both of these images using `tikz`?

Comment: Please complete your code so that it will compile when copy-pasted.

Comment: Please ask one question per question. Please show what you have tried for the second image if that is what you want this question to be about. (You can draw a square so you can make a start.)

Comment: @cfr As with the lo shu square the other day, I am thoroughly illiterate when it comes to tikz. I don't even really know what to try exactly at the moment--when I have a chance, I will go through the tikz/pgf manual to learn more about everything, but right now I just need the figures. If I can't obtain those, then I will find another workaround.

Comment: You can complete your code. You don't need to know anything about TiKZ to do that! You can also ask one question per question. You don't need to know anything about TiKZ to do that either. However, it really is not reasonable to expect other people to do the work of drawing your figures for you because you do not have time. That's not how this site works. (Somebody may oblige if sufficiently keen to procrastinate but that's a different story.) You have a couple of options. One is to hire somebody to draw the figures for you. Another is to use `\includegraphics{}`.

Comment: @cfr I'm not just trying to get people to do my work--I look over what's posted so I can learn from it. If I have to, then I will certainly use `\includegraphics{}`, just as I did with the lo shu magic square until someone helped me. I simply want to see if there's a relatively easy way of going about producing the desired figure.

Comment: You have been [asked before to provide complete examples](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215775/subscripts-with-tables#comment506728_215779), but you will not do so. That you could easily do. That you refuse to do so suggests you think others' time much less valuable than yours. Other people are giving their time to help you. The least you could do is provide compilable code. And why can't you abide by the one question per question rule? If you get 2 answers - one to each question - whose will you accept? Neither? You can't accept both.

Comment: ***Please do not down-vote this question beyond -1.*** A score of -1 is sufficient to communicate to the OP that improvement is required. Down-votes beyond that point are unnecessary and hostile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer of your first question (short answer but probably not realy good for someone who starts to use tikz) :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw,inner sep=1cm](R){};
  \draw[dashed] foreach \angle/\inlabel/\outlabel in
    {0//, 45/$D_2$/b, 90//V, 135/$D_1$/a, 180//H, 225//d, 270//, 315/p/c}
    {(R.center) -- (R.\angle) node[fill=white, pos=.5]{\inlabel} node[label=\angle:\outlabel]{}} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

And one answer to your second question :

```
\tikzset{
  rect/.style n args={4}{
    draw, thick, inner sep=1cm, label=45:#1, label=135:#2, label=225:#3, label=315:#4
  },
  arrow/.style={thick, ->,shorten <= 5mm, shorten >= 5mm}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path (0,0) node[rect=badc](A){} ++(4,0) node[rect=adcb](B){} ++(4,0) node[rect=bcda](C){};
  \draw[arrow] (A.0) -- node[pos=.5, above] {$\mu_{90}$} (B.180);
  \draw[arrow] (B.0) -- node[pos=.5, above] {$\rho_{H}$} (C.180);
  \draw[arrow] (A.90) to[bend left] node[pos=.5, above] {$\rho_{H} \circ \mu_{90}$} (C.90);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to put the letters in a math environment? I tried using `rect=$badc$` but this clearly does not work. Would the workaround be substantial or is this fairly easy to fix?

Comment: Yes, you have two possibilties: 1) change the style by putting `label=45:$#1$, label=135:$#2$, label=225:$#3$, label=315:$#4$` and keep the picture; 2) keep the style and in the picture you can use something like `rect={$b$}{$a$}{$d$}{$c$}`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is answer for your first question.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,thick]
      \foreach \name/\angle in {a/135,b/45,c/315,d/225}
        \node (\name) at (\angle:2) {\strut$\name$};
        \draw (b.south west) -- node[above=4pt](v){$V$} (a.south east) --
              node[left=2pt](h){$H$}(d.north east) -- (c.north west) -- cycle;
        \draw[dotted] (b.south west) -- node[pos=0.25,fill=white]{$D_2$} (d.north east);
        \draw[dotted] (a.south east) -- node[pos=0.25,fill=white]{$D_1$}
                                        node[pos=0.75,fill=white]{$p$}
                                        (c.north west);
        \draw[dotted] ($(b.south west)!0.5!(a.south east)$) -- ($(d.north east)!0.5!(c.north
             west)$);
         \draw[dotted] ($(d.north east)!0.5!(a.south east)$) -- ($(b.south west)!0.5!(c.north
             west)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]